# Run mysql script from network location

Tags: mysql, sql, freebsd, nas

I currently have a mysql sever installed in a Jail on my freesnas machine. I can connect to the server via MySql Workbench locally or SSH to the NAS, log into the Jail and then the mysql server.

Most of my sql scripts are saved on a networked drive that is accessible via my NAS.

Im trying to run these scripts via my second means of access. However I get, source error 2, when using the `\.` command followed by the path.

Obviously there is a problem with passing a file (or the path) on a network drive through to a remote connected to service.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `\.` command? Can you show us a complete exact command you are executing? Ideally a complete dump of the command, including its output.

Comment: 'source' command to call a script or file to the mysql server.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html